# Conditions for various levels of damping in oscillatory motion (concern about negative frequencies)

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers

Consider the following generic equation for a damped oscillator (eq 5.33 in Taylor's CM book)

$$
x(t) = e^{-\beta t} \bigg(C_1 e^{\sqrt{\beta^2-\omega_0^2}t}  + C_2 e^{-\sqrt{\beta^2-\omega_0^2}t}\bigg)
$$

derived from (5.24 and 5.28)

$$
m\ddot{x} + b \dot{x} + kx =0
$$

$$
\ddot{x} + 2\beta \dot{x} + \omega_0^2x =0
$$

Taylor notes that $\beta$ and $\omega_0$ have units of frequency. All good so far, this is clear.

But in equation 5.35 Taylor defines the condition for underdamped oscillations by $\beta<\omega_0$. This is uses to say that the square root terms in the exponential are imaginary....

How is this so? What about negative frequencies? $\beta=-5 \text{ second}^{-1} < \omega_0=3 \text{ second}^{-1}$ but the square root $\sqrt{25-9}=4$ is clearly not imaginary.

Comment: I never understood why physicists use this idiotic notation $2\beta \dot x$ for the damping term. If you want to introduce a parameter that represents the amount of damping, put $\omega_0$ in the damping term to represent the "units" of frequency, and then the parameter is dimensionless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damping constant $\beta$ and the angular frequency (eigenmode) of the oscillator $\omega_0$ are both positive (not negative). However, the damping constant is smaller than the eigenfrequency, $0\le \beta \le \omega_0$.

Here an example:
\begin{align}
\beta &= 189 Hz \\
\omega_0 &=200.1 Hz
\end{align}
Although both are positive the damping constant is smaller than the eigenfrequency and the exponent becomes complex.

Answer (score 0):

If a second order linear homogeneous ODE has a Characteristic Equation with complex roots, then the general form of the solution is:

$$y(t)=c_1e^{\lambda t}\cos \mu t+c_2 e^{\lambda t}\sin \mu t$$

For roots:

$$r_{1,2}=\lambda \pm \mu i$$

[Reference and derivation](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ComplexRoots.aspx).

So that form is different from the one you described.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{at}$ only represents an oscillation when $a$ is imaginary. If $a$ is real, it is just an exponential curve.

Consider what happens when $b = \beta = 0$. Obviously there is no damping at all. The solution is then
$$x(t)=C_1e^{iω_0t} + C_2e^{−iω_0t}$$
which is undamped simple harmonic motion.

For an underdamped system, the damping is the $e^{-\beta t}$ term, and the other term is again undamped oscillation, but with a different (lower) frequency that depends on the amount of damping.